# author_picture twig variable outputting title and bio?

Tags: theming, 8

Reading the D8 documentation, it says the appropriate twig for displaying the author's picture is:

{{author_picture}}

When I use that, however, I'm getting the author's title, and description as well.  Is there a way to fix that other than CSS fixes to render the other fields invisible?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!templates!node.html.twig/8.2.x), {{author_picture}} is showing the node author user entity, rendered using the "compact" view mode.

In other words, you can adapt it by browsing to `http://your_site/admin/config/people/accounts/display/compact`